# Custom (de)serializer in Jackson with generic wrapper class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm making a generic list wrapper, one that holds meta information and the actual data (list). It is [Vert.x](https://vertx.io) project, and because of the EventBus, that wrapper must support serialization to and deserialization from JSON.

Simple usage:

`Wrapper<SomeType> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(metaInfo, list);`

I thought using Jackson might be the simplest way (because Vert.x also uses Jackson in background).

`SomeType` can be any type that my team uses, it can be a generated POJO or some library type (such as `JsonObject` from Vert.x). This is important because we cannot change that type (e.g. add default constructor, getters/setters etc.) or annotate it (e.g. `@JsonProperty`, `@JsonCreator` etc.), only write custom (de)serializers if needed.

To be able to deserialize JSON to appropriate type, some additional information is needed, and with Jackson that can be achieved via `@JsonTypeInfo`. So my (simplified for this question) wrapper class looks like this:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    @JsonProperty("info")
    private String someInfo;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "@class")
    private List<T> data;

    @JsonCreator
    public Wrapper(@JsonProperty("info") String someInfo, @JsonProperty("data") List<T> data) {
        this.someInfo = someInfo;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static <T> Wrapper<T> fromJson(String json) {
        if (json == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        //in test, I've hard coded deserializer for ProblematicClass
        module.addDeserializer(ProblematicClass.class, new ProblematicClassDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot deserialize Wrapper from Json. Message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public String toJson() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        //in test, I've hard coded deserializer for ProblematicClass
        module.addSerializer(ProblematicClass.class, new ProblematicClassSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot serialize Wrapper to Json. Message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if type is "Jackson serializable" (e.g. has default constructor, getters/setters and etc), but if not, problems occur. Here is a example class that is problematic. I wrote this class as a test alias for Vert.x's `JsonObject` so that MVCE is minimal, there is no need for Vert.x dependency.

```
class ProblematicClass {
    private Map<String, Object> map;

    public ProblematicClass() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public ProblematicClass put(String key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public ProblematicClass put(String key, Integer value) {
        map.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }
    //put (..., boolean), put (..., Float) etc.

    public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        //e.g. some internal logic (as for JsonObject)
        //this is just example (I know that everything is written as string)
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    }

    public static ProblematicClass fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        ProblematicClass instance = new ProblematicClass();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        instance.map = (Map<String, Object>) mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        return instance;
    }
    //getString, getInteger, getFloat etc.
}
```

This class obviously needs custom serializer/deserializer, because it has e.g. `isEmpty` that cannot be deserialized. Remember, we "cannot" change this class, it is e.g. from external library.

So, this code succeeds in serializing (producing incorrect JSON) and fails on deserialization:

```
List<ProblematicClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(ProblematicClass.fromJson("{\"a\": \"10\"}"));
list.add(ProblematicClass.fromJson("{\"b\": \"20\"}"));
Wrapper<ProblematicClass> wrapper = new Wrapper<>("info", list);
String json = wrapper.toJson();
```

Produced JSON looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","map":{"a":"10"},"empty":false},
{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","map":{"b":"20"},"empty":false}],"info":"info"}
```

And it is not deserializable because `empty` JSON key. So, we need to write serializer and deserializer:

```
class ProblematicClassSerializer extends StdSerializer<ProblematicClass> {
    public ProblematicClassSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected ProblematicClassSerializer(Class<ProblematicClass> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(ProblematicClass value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        WritableTypeId typeId = typeSer.typeId(value, START_OBJECT);
        typeSer.writeTypePrefix(gen, typeId);
        gen.writeFieldName("@json");
        serialize(value, gen, serializers);  //our custom serialize method written below
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(gen, typeId);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ProblematicClass value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeRawValue(value == null ? null : value.toJson());
    }
}

class ProblematicClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ProblematicClass> {
    public ProblematicClassDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected ProblematicClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public ProblematicClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser).toString(); //this is actual json representation
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class); //I know this is redundant, but for example it is fine
        return json == null ? null : ProblematicClass.fromJson(mapper.writeValueAsString(map.get("@json")));
        //sometimes I got {"key": "value"} //when serialize is called (ProblematicClass wrapped)
        //and sometimes I got {"@json": {"key": "value"}} //when using bare ProblematicClass as in Wrapper<ProblematicClass>
        //I need to distinguish these two cases but I don't know when is te first and when second
        //because deserializationContext is not giving me these information
    }
}
```

As I understand `serialize` is called when `ProblematicClass` is attribute in another class (e.g. `SomeRealClass` written bellow) and resulting JSON will be `{"pclass": {"a": 10}}` which is okay. Because of that I used `jgen.writeRawValue` in `serialize`.

```
class SomeRealClass {
    public ProblematicClass pclass = ProblematicClass.fromJson("{\"a\": \"10\"}");
    public Integer i1 = 10, i2 = 20;

    SomeRealClass() throws IOException {
    }
}
```

`serializeWithType` is used when I serialize `ProblematicClass` alone, then resulting JSON will be `{"a": 10}`, which is also okay.

But, because I use `@JsonTypeInfo` in `Wrapper`, Jackson injects its type info (`"@class": "com.test.ProblematicClass"`), and that causes problem with the second example (`{"a": 10}`). So, in `serializeWithType` I've written `gen.writeFieldName("@json");` to "wrap" the JSON, so it should look like this (with Jackson's meta info):

```
{"info":"info","data":[{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","@json":{"a":"10"}},
{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","@json":{"b":"20"}}]}
```

This is fine until deserialization. I cannot distinguish which type of serialization is used, the one without `@json` (e.g. `"pclass": {"a": 10}`) or with `@json`. `map.get("@json")` returns `null` in former case (when `serialize` is called).

With all this said, there is code with comments elaborated above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //without (de)serializes this does not work as it's json is not deserializable (because of 'empty' key)
    //   {"data":[{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","map":{"a":"10"},"empty":false},
    //     {"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","map":{"b":"20"},"empty":false}],"info":"info"}
    //when I hardcode (de)serializer then this (correct) json is produced:
    //   {"info":"info","data":[{"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","@json":{"a":"10"}},
    //     {"@class":"com.test.ProblematicClass","@json":{"b":"20"}}]}
    {
        List<ProblematicClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(ProblematicClass.fromJson("{\"a\": \"10\"}"));
        list.add(ProblematicClass.fromJson("{\"b\": \"20\"}"));
        Wrapper<ProblematicClass> wrapper = new Wrapper<>("info", list);
        String json = wrapper.toJson();
        Wrapper<ProblematicClass> copy = Wrapper.fromJson(json);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //but, when container class is used (SomeRealClass)
    //this @json is redundant, so I wrote it only in serializeWithType
    //resulting JSON is correct? there is no @json, like: "problematicClass": {"@json": {"a": "10}}
    //and deserialization fails (map.get("@json") is null)
    //    {"info":"info-real","data":[{"@class":"com.test.SomeRealClass","problematicClass":{"a":"10"},"i1":10,"i2":20},
    //       {"@class":"com.test.SomeRealClass","problematicClass":{"a":"10"},"i1":10,"i2":20}]}
    {
        List<SomeRealClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SomeRealClass());
        list.add(new SomeRealClass());
        Wrapper<SomeRealClass> wrapper = new Wrapper<>("info-real", list);
        String json = wrapper.toJson();
        Wrapper<SomeRealClass> copy = Wrapper.fromJson(json);
    }
}
```

Here is the full working MVCE on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kxwjS4yD).

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem? But, please, do not suggest "always wrap type in wrapper" e.g. `class ProblematicClassHolder {public ProblematicClass pclass; }`.

Thank you very much for reading this long question and, of course, for all comments and answers.

Comment: Anyone? I just need to know in custom deserializer wheather serializeWithType is called?